# Having problems with res.redirect in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have been trying to input my location from the search form and it logs in the console but the res.redirect doesn't take me to a new url. (Given URL was just an example)

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

// Utils
const geocode = require('./utils/geocode');
const forecast = require('./utils/weatherstack');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors())

let location;

app.post('/search-location', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        location = await req.body.location
        return res.redirect('https://www.google.com')
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }    
})

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log("server is up and running on 9000");
})
```

Comment: A note: in `await req.body.location` the `await` doesn't do anything since req.body.location is not a promise

Answer (score 0):

I trimmed down your code and the following snippet gives me correct redirects:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.post('/search-location', async (req,res) => {
    try {
        return res.redirect('https://www.google.com')
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    }    
})

app.listen(9000, () => {
  console.log("server is up and running on 9000");
})
```

```
curl -X POST localhost:9000/search-location
```

```
*   Trying ::1:9000...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /search-location HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Location: https://www.google.com
< Vary: Accept
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 44
< Date: Thu, 07 May 2020 16:37:00 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Found. Redirecting to https://www.google.com
```

Your issue is most likely with `location = await req.body.location` since `req.body.location` is not a promise (just a parsed POST body object by the client, it cannot be awaited`

Maybe you meant to wrap it in a function:

```
location = await computeFunction(req.body.location)
```